# Visio VBA EMF Transparency

Tags: vba, visio

In Visio VBA it's possible to set the transparency of a shape, including raster images.  However, imported EMF shapes don't respond to the different fill, line, or image transparency cell changes other shapes do.

Is it possible to apply transparency to imported EMF image shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ungroup the EMF shape and the set values in the individual shapes which are created after ungroup operation.